# Unable to download a complete db file

Tags: r, curl

I'm trying to download a db file from a GitHub repo using the following code:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(curl)

url <- "https://github.com/kotartemiy/newscatcher/tree/master/newscatcher/data/package_rss.db"
curl::curl_download(url = url,
              destfile = "inst/external-data/package_rss.db",
              quiet = TRUE, mode = "wb")
```

Which works, but downloads the file size between 79Kb and 82Kb (depending on which mode I use). But when I try to access the database file I get the warning:

```
sqlite.driver <- dbDriver("SQLite")
db <- dbConnect(sqlite.driver,
                dbname = "inst/external-data/package_rss.db")
```

> Warning message:
> Couldn't set synchronous mode: file is not a database
> Use `synchronous` = NULL to turn off this warning.

Followed by the error:

```
dbListTables(db)
```

> Error: file is not a database

This can be reproduced using `download.file()` and different `mode` arguments. However, if I download the file manually it has 376 Kb and the RSQLite code works without any problems. What may be causing the issue? Thanks

Comment: You're downloading the github page and not the file - use URL `https://github.com/kotartemiy/newscatcher/raw/master/newscatcher/data/package_rss.db`

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @27ϕ9 said, you're downloading a webpage, not the file it references.

```r
url <- "https://github.com/kotartemiy/newscatcher/tree/master/newscatcher/data/package_rss.db"
download.file(url, "~/Downloads/package_rss.db")
# trying URL 'https://github.com/kotartemiy/newscatcher/tree/master/newscatcher/data/package_rss.db'
# Content type 'text/html; charset=utf-8' length unknown
# downloaded 82 KB

readLines("~/Downloads/package_rss.db", n=10)
#  [1] ""                                                                      
#  [2] ""                                                                      
#  [3] ""                                                                      
#  [4] ""                                                                      
#  [5] ""                                                                      
#  [6] "<!DOCTYPE html>"                                                       
#  [7] "<html lang=\"en\">"                                                    
#  [8] "  <head>"                                                              
#  [9] "    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">"                                          
# [10] "  <link rel=\"dns-prefetch\" href=\"https://github.githubassets.com\">"
```

If you go to that URL in a browser, you'll see two links on the page:

1. the "Download" button pushes you to a link under raw.githubusercontent.com ([link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kotartemiy/newscatcher/master/newscatcher/data/package_rss.db)), so you can hunt for that URL;
2. There's also a "view raw" link, which takes the same URL you started with, replaces the `/tree/` with `/blob/`, and appends `?raw=true` ([link](https://github.com/kotartemiy/newscatcher/blob/master/newscatcher/data/package_rss.db?raw=true)).

[image]

(While it's possible to ha`rvest` the html and get the link programmatically, I think just starting with the correct URL is the preferred route.)